# How to grab stream url with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

EDIT:

My updated PHP Code:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Referer: http://www.ucaster.me/hembedplayer/shid05/1/1/1" .
  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.ucaster.me/hembedplayer/shid05/1/1/1', false, stream_context_create($opts));
preg_match("/playlist\.m3u8\?id=([^&=>]+).*?enableVideo\("([^"]*)/s", $url, $m);
$video_id = $m[1];
$video_pk = $m[2];

echo $video_pk;
?>
```

What I have to do is pull the stream pk inside the source

Page Source (same as before):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var videoPlayer = document.createElement("video");
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("id", "videoplayer");
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("width", "580");
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("height", "450");
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("poster", "/static/images/logo.png");
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("autoplay", true);
                videoPlayer.setAttribute("controls", "");       

                var em = document.createElement("em");
                em.innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.";
                videoPlayer.appendChild(em);

                document.getElementById("player_div").appendChild(videoPlayer);

                function setupVideo() {
                        if (Hls.isSupported()) {    
                            var video = document.getElementById('videoplayer');
                            var player = new Hls();
                            player.attachMedia(video);
                            player.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
                                var hlsUrl = "http://" + ea + ":8088/live/shid04/playlist.m3u8?id=95328&pk=";
                                hlsUrl = hlsUrl + enableVideo("5be02e45f5917b29199f8e5326499a6f8c6c7c9df86920b38c09bee46b050289");
                                player.loadSource(hlsUrl);
                                player.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {  
                                    video.play();
                                });
                            });
                        }else {
                            em.innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.";
                        }
                    }

            </script>
```

I am trying to display in echo the pk like this:

5be02e45f5917b29199f8e5326499a6f8c6c7c9df86920b38c09bee46b050289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://regex101.com/r/aIxtsI/1

```
preg_match("/playlist\.m3u8\?id=([^&=>]+).*?enableVideo\("([^"]*)/s", $input, $m);
$video_id = $m[1];
$video_pk = $m[2];
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check it in the next hours. i have a problem with the Referer for the web player. I will fix and check the regex. Happy New Year:)